# Asset_audio_player instance destroyed as playlist ends

Tags: flutter, audio-player

I am trying to understand the code base of the asset audio player flutter package so that I can implement it in one of my apps.
I am noticing some strange behavior which the app is showing.
Every time when I add a playlist to play through the asset audioplayer instance when the last song gets completed the whole instance is deleted automatically and a blank screen is displayed in place of the audio player
I am attaching a video for reference.
Link for the video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qMarmwmCkoYVbKSyAYw9aplPkRZ5jLQw/view?usp=sharing

Output i am getting in the debug console:

```
D/AudioTrack(17624): stop() called with 196992 frames delivered
I/ExoPlayerImpl(17624): Release bc9e881 [ExoPlayerLib/2.13.2] [vince, Redmi Note 5, Xiaomi, 27] [goog.exo.core]
W/MediaAnalyticsItem(17624): Unable to record: (codec:0:-1:-11:0:5:android.media.mediacodec.codec=OMX.google.mp3.decoder:android.media.mediacodec.mode=audio:android.media.mediacodec.secure=0:android.media.mediacodec.mime=audio/mpeg:android.media.mediacodec.bytesin=318694:) [forcenew=0]
I/flutter (17624): playlistAudioFinished : Playing{audio: PlayingAudio{audio: Audio{path: assets/audios/instrumental.mp3, package: null, audioType: AudioType.asset, _metas: Instance of 'Metas', _networkHeaders: null}, duration: 0:04:04.976000}, index: 0, hasNext: false, playlist: ReadingPlaylist{audios: [Audio{path: assets/audios/instrumental.mp3, package: null, audioType: AudioType.asset, _metas: Instance of 'Metas', _networkHeaders: null}], currentIndex: 0}}
```

Comment: Better to post some relevant code.

Comment: Here is the code base: https://github.com/florent37/Flutter-AssetsAudioPlayer.git

Comment: As i mentioned i am trying to understand the implementation first from the code base present in the package. @DarShan

Comment: Well if you are having an issue on the example built by the library author, better file an issue there.

Comment: Already done. Asking here as well because there are chances someone has encountered this error and has a fix.

Comment: Do you have a fix for this or have faced this issue? @DarShan

Comment: I haven't used this plugin but you can try this one maybe: https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

Comment: I have implemented my use case with this plugin but this does not serve the purpose.
It stops the player once the song is completed and not plays the next song in the form of a playlist.
Any other alternative? @DarShan